# 0: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username']!=""){

$db = JFactory::getDBO();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query

->select($db->quoteName(array('username','slot', 'date_time', 'status')));
->from($db->quoteName('ph_table'));
->where($db->quoteName('username') . ' = '.$db->quote($username));
->order('username ASC');
$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();
}

else {

    echo "<center><font color='red'><strong>Oops!!&nbsp;&nbsp;Invalid     Entry</strong></font></center>";}

?>
```

I want to retrieve values for username, slot, date_time and status fields on my joomla database table '#_table'. when this code is executed i get,

> 0:syntax error, unexpected '->'(T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

. I am stuck! a help would be fantastic!

Comment: On what line do you get this error?

Comment: @Jerodev am using sourcer php plugin on joomla, so code line number isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use semicolon's in:

```
$query
->select($db->quoteName(array('username','slot', 'date_time', 'status')))
->from($db->quoteName('ph_table'))
->where($db->quoteName('username') . ' = '.$db->quote($username))
->order('username ASC');
```

Comment: thanks radek! it worked. no errors but no records were retrieved/selected from my database table...